# 'aastex.cls' not found after texlive-publishers already installed?

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu, texlive-2016, aastex

I am using Texlive2016 with Texworks on Ubuntu16.04.

The document is

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\begin{document}
blabla
\end{document}
```

To install `aastex`, I do `sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers`. This worked when the OS was Ubuntu 14.04. However, now on Ubuntu 16.04, after correctly installed texlive-publishers, it still keeps telling me that `aastex.cls` is not found.

How to fix this error? Or are there any alternative ways to install `aastex`?

P.S. `sudo find / -name aastex.cls` returns nothing. I guess this means `aastex` has not been installed correctly. But `sudo apt-cache search aastex` shows that it is included in `texlive-publishers` and there is no error reported while installing this package. Why?

Comment: you can download the classfile from http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex.html

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  there is an `aastex6.cls` in tex live.  maybe that is what you're looking for?

Comment: There is no longer `aastex.cls` in TeX Live; as far as I can see it was withdrawn between 2014 and 2015. The class is now named `aastex6`

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The right name is 'aastex6.cls' and it fixed this error. Thank you very very much!